# Tag hovers don't work on sites with MathJax enabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, mathjax, popups

On sites with MathJax enabled, e.g. [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com), [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) and [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) (thanks @NogShine), hovering over the tags doesn't display the excerpt and statistics anymore. The tag *does* get highlighted when you hover over it:

[image]

Tested on macOS 10.13.3 with the latest Safari and Firefox. Sites without MathJax, including Meta Stack Exchange, are not affected:

[image]

As @ShadowWizard notes, the problem is caused by the JavaScript file necessary to render MathJax.

Comment: [Aviation.se] also.

Comment: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined*.

Comment: I get a different error upon hovering: *TypeError: c.nodeName is undefined[Learn More]*

Comment: The above client side error occurs in Tex-Latex related file, so it means tags popup won't work on any site with Tex-Latex enabled

Comment: Yep, Math.SE is affected as well.

Comment: Marc (Gravell) is on top of this, hopefully he'll hunt the bug down soon and fix it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard wait... I said I'd take a look; you may be grossly misunderstanding my UI/javascript skills :)

Comment: @Marc heh... I have faith in you. Worst case scenario, you see who committed the change with the bug and poke them with a sharp stick until they fix the bug. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build rev `2018.3.29.29636` or greater.

The tag hover menu code was passing a jQuery object (instead of the underlying DOM element it was wrapping) to `MathJax.Hub.Typeset`.

I've also bumped MathJax to the latest minor version (`2.7.2` -> `2.7.3`).